# Distinguish my APP vs cloned APP when accessing data from server

Tags: android, security, http

I have a website which supplies data to mobile app.
`Is there a way to identify myApp vs a cloned App?`
So that I can block access of any cloned App.

On first time APP usage, I generate an `APP ID`, `PASS CODE` & `Access URL`
Where I change the `PASS CODE` frequently, but how to identify myAPP on the first access so as to be sure that I am issuing `APP ID` & `PASS CODE` to my own APP only.

What sort of encryption I can use for the first time access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a hardcoded key on your app code that only your server knows. Use it to create a hash signature, like `md5(concat(key, deviceId))`. When the requests arrive to your application server, you can do the same and compare the results. The clonner can't discover this key by sniffing your app requests. The only way to get it is by disassembling it, but it's much harder.

This is a simple suggestion, though. If you want a more sofisticated solution, check for [HMAC wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense passing a token via Push to an application ([GCM for Android](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)). Using that code can uniquely identify application, and cloned application could not reach that code.